# Confused about shallow copy of array using slice() (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, slice

I thought that when using the `slice() method`, we were just making a `shallow copy`, meaning that if I modify any value of the copy that is referenced, it will be reflected on the original too.

Example:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
  { name: "Chris", lastName: "Dior" },
];

const arrCopy = arr.slice(); // Creating shallow copy

arrCopy[0].name = "Stella"; // Changed in copy AND original as it should
arrCopy.pop(); // Deleting last element of the copy, ONLY disappears in the copy

console.log(arr); // has both elements
console.log(arrCopy); // has only one
```

Why does the second object is gone just in the shallow copy? I thought the arr and arrCopy were pointing to the same object. (an array with objects)

Thanks in advance, Im really new to programming in general and this topic is getting confusing sometimes.

Comment: The values in *arr* are **references** to objects, that's what gets copied to *arrCopy*. When you do `arrCopy.pop()` you remove the last value (i.e. reference to an object) from *arrCopy*. Also, when you do `arrCopy[0].name = "Stella"` you are changing the object referenced by both arrays, you aren't actually changing the array *per se*. :-)

Comment: You said "if I modify any value of the copy that is referenced, it will be reflected on the original", but this is NOT what a shallow copy means. A shallow copy is a completely new, unrelated array that is a COPY of the original (so it has the same contents.) The "shallow" part is that if the contents contain any reference values (Objects, Arrays, Functions, etc -- as opposed to primitives like numbers and strings), then when one of those referenced items changes (by any means), both references will still point to the (now changed) item so the changes will be visible via the references.

Answer (score 2):

It's just as you're saying here:

```
const arrCopy = arr.slice(); // Creating shallow copy
```

The new array is separate from the old array. Changing the new array structure *without changing any of its containing objects* will result in only the new array changing, not the old array changing.

> I thought the arr and arrCopy were pointing to the same object. (an array with objects)

No. Both `arr` and `arrCopy` are *separate containers*. Those containers contain pointers to the same objects, but the *containers themselves* are different - so, changing one of the containers doesn't change the other container.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.